# Set gradle.ext in settings.gradle.kts with Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, groovy

Here's code snippet from [google/exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) - which is written in Groovy buildscript.

```
// settings.gradle
gradle.ext.exoplayerRoot = 'path/to/exoplayer'
gradle.ext.exoplayerModulePrefix = 'exoplayer-'
apply from: new File(gradle.ext.exoplayerRoot, 'core_settings.gradle')
```

How can I achieve this using Kotlin DSL?

I couldn't find any useful resources or documents. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any help? https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples/extra-properties

Comment: @tim_yates I've already seen it, but it doesn't tell me about how can I access extra properties within Gradle object.

Comment: I'm currently digging into it. Does Groovy accepts dynamic implementation of an Interface? That might be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution after digging a while.

In Groovy, there's dynamic implementation of traits - So even if class A does not implement interface B in the class definition, it may implement it later in the future.

I didn't see Gradle internals so I can't properly explain this, but it seems to work. Hope this helps.

```
if (gradle is ExtensionAware) {
    val extension = gradle as ExtensionAware
    extension.extra["exoplayerRoot"] = "path/to/exoplayer"
    extension.extra["exoplayerModulePrefix"] = "exoplayer-"
    apply(from = File(extension.extra["exoplayerRoot"].toString(), "core_settings.gradle"))
}
```

For those who uses ExoPlayer, I created an [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6339) for requesting some documents for Kotlin DSL users.